# PHP function calls through AJAX just reload page.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a new script and I am trying to add a PHP function to send an email.  I have nested a couple of Ajax calls in a JavaScript function.  Every time I call it it just reloads the page.

I am including jquery and the JavaScript library with the following.

```
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The button where I call the function is as follows.

```
    <button type="button" onclick="jq1()"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

The JavaScript and AJAX functions are part of a library that I have included.  The details on this are as follows.

The JavaScript function is

```
    function jq1 () {

            doAjax();

            }
```

Which in turn calls the following AJAX.

```
   function doAjax()

    {

        var name, email, message;
        name = JSON.stringify($('name').val();
        email = JSON.stringify($('email').val();
        message = JSON.stringify($('message').val();

        ajax = phpcall(name, email, message);

    }
```

And here is the Jquery for the actual php function call.

```
    function phpcall (name, email, message)

     {

        return $.ajax({

           { url: 'file.php', 
             type: 'POST', 
             data: { email: email, name: name, message: message } 

            return false; 
        });

     }
```

The PHP I have tested form Command Line and it works.  Here is the detail on the actual PHP call.

```
   <?php
    function mail2() {

        if (isset($_POST['name']))
          (
            $name = json_decode(sanitize($_POST['name']));
        )

        if (isset($_POST['email']))
        (
             $email = json_decode(sanitize($_POST['email']));
        )

        if (isset($_POST['message']))
          (
            $email = json_decode(sanitize($_POST['email']));
         )

       $to = "willdoit.winchester@gmail.com";
       $subject = "Service Inquiry";
       $txt = $message . $email;
       $headers = "From: service@willdoitwinchester.com";

        mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
      }
     ?>
```

I am brand new to Ajax and JQuery, but, I can't help feeling like I am reinventing the wheel, here.

I include JQuery in the declarations, do I need separate declarations for JSON and AJAX?   Is there a syntax error in the detail that I have provided?  This would be a normal progression of function calls right (JavaScript, two nested AJAX calls and then PHP?)?  Am I missing something that a pro would take one look and see?

Comment: If main.js includes any jQuery then you need to include it after you include jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Hy, sorry but i don't understand a thing you write

```
name = JSON.stringify($('name').val();
```

First is missing of an end bracket and the # to recovery the value but this is the minor problem, so the code must be

```
name = JSON.stringify($('#name').val());
```

But the problem is another JSON.stringify is converting an OBJECT into a string so i really don't undertand your written because i suppose that $('#name').val() is a value not an object.
So resolving this problem but only you can know why you are doing a JSON stringify of a value and not of a JSON object, there are other problems, the sanitize function that you use in PHP is a personal function?otherwise is going in error...
return false inside the Ajax object written in that way what means?What do you mean with return false?
Btw the code must be rewritten in this way, but there is alwasy the problem of the JSON.stringify that i really don't understand.
Another problem is how you switch inside the mail2 function in the file.php?This is another question but i suppose that you are doing that well...
Btw this work.

Ps : But why JSON stringify? ;)

HTML

```
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="email">
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="Descrizione">         
            <label for="InserisciDescrizione" class=""><b>Descrizione : </b></label>
            <textarea id='message' placeholder="Inserisci Descrizione"
                      name='message'  rows='5' cols='60' value="" 
                      title="Descrizione"></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btnEmail" onclick="jq1()">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
    function jq1 () {
            doAjax();
    }
   function doAjax(){
        var name, email, message;
        name = JSON.stringify($('#name').val());
        email = JSON.stringify($('#email').val());
        message = JSON.stringify($('#message').val());
        ajax = phpcall(name, email, message);
    }       
    function phpcall (name, email, message){
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'file.php', 
             type: 'POST', 
             data: { email: email, name: name, message: message } 
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
        function mail2() {
            if (isset($_POST['name'])){
                $name = json_decode($_POST['name']);
              }

            if (isset($_POST['email'])){
                 $email = json_decode($_POST['email']);
            }
            if (isset($_POST['message'])){
                $message= json_decode($_POST['message']);
        }

           $to = "willdoit.winchester@gmail.com";
           $subject = "Service Inquiry";
           $txt = $message . $email;
           $headers = "From: service@willdoitwinchester.com";
            //print '1' .$name .'2' .$email .$message;exit;
            mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
          }
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax errors and I am still getting the same thing.  I added some logging to the initial JavaScript function call and the log file that I am trying to write to is not populating.

Comment: I suggest to download jquery 3.2 from the site after copy and paste my code...in the PHP you will see a line commented, after including jquery 3 you can decomment the line and see in console browser(F12) in chrome or firefox under network if the parameters are correct..I tried my code and the email arrive but in spam folder, to do a valid code that doesn't go in spam folder i can send you in private.Bye

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the syntax errors and the page is no longer reloading, but, the email is not being sent.

I added some logging to the initial JavaScript call as follows.

```
          function jq1 () {

             var txtFile = "/tmp/test.txt";
             var file = new File(txtFile);

             file.open("w"); // open file with write access
             file.writeln("First line of text");
             file.close();

            doAjax();

            }
```

And the text file is not populating with anything.  Nothing is being written.

I then moved the JQuery and AJAX functions out of the library and into the HTML as follows.

```
      <script language="javascript">
          function jq1 () {

           var txtFile = "/tmp/test.txt";
           var file = new File(txtFile);

           file.open("w"); // open file with write access
           file.writeln("First line of text");
           file.close();

            doAjax();

          }

          function phpcall (name, email, message)

            {

                        return $.ajax({

                                 url: 'file.php', 
                                 type: 'POST', 
                                 data: { email: email, name: name, message: message } 


                      });

             }


          function doAjax()

                    {

                var name, email, message;
                        name = JSON.stringify($('#name').val());
                        email = JSON.stringify($('#email').val());
                        message = JSON.stringify($('@message').val());

                ajax = phpcall(name, email, message);

                    }

</script>
```

This still resulted in the same thing.  The button clicks nothing happens.

Am I supposed to do any language includes in the script?  I am really only declaring the following.

```
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems there is something fundamentally wrong with either the declarations or the button tag where I call the functions.  I am including that below.

```
     <button type="button" id="btnEmail"
                        onclick="jq1()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

It seems simple enough to me.

Sorry it took me a while to do the testing.  We web script largely works.  Any suggestions?